# PgAgent jobs not executing on remote server

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I don't understand why this isn't working, I set up a pgAgent job to send a `NOTIFY` from the database every hour

[image]

The steps

[image]

The schedule

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? What is recieving the notify (or supposed to)? IIRC most client do not "react" to notify (async) but rather require pseudo polling.

Comment: Another app that receives all of the notify's isn't receiving that particular notify, it deals fine with others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that problem was that heroku doesn't support agAgent and the database was running on heroku, I ended making a work around the scheduling tasks using windows task scheduler - it's not the best solution but it does the job I needed to do...

Comment: your using windows on Heroku?